# Unable to get data from remote json using jQuery ajax()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Helle there,
I would like to take the value "localidade" in this json: https://viacep.com.br/ws/35400000/json
but unfortunataly my code is not working and I do not know why.
My PHP code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(cep){
        var URL = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/";
        URL += cep;
        URL += "/json/";
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: URL,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data["localidade"])
            }
        });
    }

    <?php
        $cep = 35400000;
        echo "calculate($cep);";
    ?>
</script>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Did it show any error when you run the code?

Comment: The code works on my local. You should double-check it.

Comment: I run only Javascript in my browser, It works too. 
What is the error you get? Maybe the problem is from the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right but you are using PHP in js to call a method there are 2 ways
1st: pass value from PHP to js and call method from js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(cep){
        var URL = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/";
        URL += cep;
        URL += "/json/";
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: URL,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data["localidade"])
            }
        });
    }
    var cep= 35400000 //<?=json_encode($value)?>;
    calculate(cep);
</script>
```

2nd: call js function from PHP

```
$cep=35400000;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'calculate("$cep");',
     '</script>'
;

<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(cep){
        var URL = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/";
        URL += cep;
        URL += "/json/";
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: URL,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data["localidade"])
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try any of solution and tell me is it working ?

Comment: Is not working yet. In my first code, when I put the alert function inside the funcion calculate, is working, but when I put inside the $.ajax, is not working

Comment: bro you need to add jquery first. Without that how can you use ajax request?

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: add this script tag in your code

Comment: I found the problem bro. I forgot to add the jquery library in the project! Thanks!